# Is there a temp file in Ubuntu?

Tags: files

This have happen to me many times:

I should pass the result of one command  to file. After using result via that, That becomes useless. So I should remove that in order to make my directory clean :-{|

But the point is I forget delete that file. Is there any way in Ubuntu to handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the directory `/tmp` it is emptied at next reboot

Answer (score 4):

Yes, every Linux distribution, including Ubuntu, has a directory

`/tmp`

Every user has write access right in this directory, hence can create files inside it. Those files are not kept forever - content of the `/tmp` directory is deleted after each system reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You do not tell whether you're writing compiled code or using Bash?

Tested Bash scripting:

```
template=/tmp/$(basename $0)_$(date --rfc-3339=date)__$$__XXXXXXXX
template="$(echo -n "$template" | tr ' ' '_')"
file=$(mktemp -u $template)
echo $file
```

Example output: `/tmp/bash_2014-07-25__4772__nrzQXfMg`

Repeat from `file=` (the last two lines) for new filenames...

Answer (score 1):

You could consider doing either of the following:

1. Using [tmpfile()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tmpfile.html) will create a file that will remain open until your program ends.
2. Using [shm_open()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/shm_open.html) may be better if your goal is to be able to do inter-process communication.

If the there is a security concern necessitating the removal of the file - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889277/how-to-create-temporary-files-on-linux-that-will-automatically-clean-up-after-th) link will be interesting for you.